# How to decode a txt file into an image?

Tags: arrays, image, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have a txt file containing the pixel values. How can I make it into an image.

Answer (score 1):

I struggling to understand what the issue is, and what you mean by *"normal"* methods and *"normal"* quality.

Your data doesn't appear to match your code. If you run this command to print the line number and number of fields on the line:

```
awk '{print NR,NF}' *txt
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 2
6 2
7 1393
8 1393
9 1393
10 1393
11 1393
12 1393
13 1393
...
...
1043 1393
1044 1393
1045 1393
1046 1393
```

You will note that:

- there are 6 lines to skip at the start, not 8
- there are 1393 items on each line, not 1040
- there are 1040 rows, not 1392

---

If you want the values saved/represented as true floating point numbers, you can save them as a TIFF file which can represent floats, alternatively use a [PFM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pfm.html) file which is understood by **GIMP**, **Photoshop** and **ImageMagick** at least.

```
import cv2

... your existing code ...

# Make data frame into Numpy array
data = data.iloc[:, :]
na = np.array(data)

# Save as TIFF
cv2.imwrite('result.tif', na)
```

[image]